# how to hide navigation bar when add flutter to existing iOS app

Tags: objective-c, flutter

how to hide navigation bar when add flutter to existing iOS app. I don't want to hide navigation bar in the iOS page.

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Share your code.

Answer (score 1):

I know nothing about Flutter, but like any view controller, flutterViewController.navigationController will return nil until it's actually a child of the navigation controller.  In your code you have just created it but not added it anywhere.  So the rest of that line (setting the navigation bar hidden to YES) is never actually executed.

Call `self.navigationController.navigationBarHidden = YES;` to hide it, in that code, since self is in the view controller hierarchy (and it's the same nav controller instance you are targeting anyways).

Comment: Hi, Carl, it works! Thank you so much. It is weird that I tried this before, and it didn't work, so I posted this question. When you mentioned this, I tried again, and it worked this time.

Comment: Thank you for your explanation of flutterViewController.navigationController.

Answer (score 0):

Apply some delay, I applied delay of 0.01secs and worked for me.

```
let flutterViewController =
        FlutterViewController(engine: flutterEngine, nibName: nil, bundle: nil)
        Timer.scheduledTimer(withTimeInterval: TimeInterval(0.01), repeats: false) {
            _ in
            flutterViewController.navigationController?.isNavigationBarHidden = true
        }
```